# Adding Datetime Picker on ng2-admin

Tags: angular, datetime, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap, ng2-admin

I am not able to figure out how to get going with Datetime picker on ng2-admin. I have tried and got it displaying such as in the attached picture:
[image]

Two problems I am stuck with are:

1. Why does the control not displaying full?
2. The clicking on the icon is not working, no errors in the console either.

Someone if can share some information on this please.

Comment: could you post some code and/or plnkr?

Comment: `<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-3'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>`

Answer (score 1):

After trying various other options I resorted to very simple HTML5 that solved my problem for now. I used following instead: 
 `<input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" formControlName="arrivedat" class="form-control" id="input03">`. 
 It is working pretty decently 
 [image]

humbly requesting, if someone finds some better solution (doing it with material is my target) please share it.

Comment: unfortunately type="datetime-local" doesn't works on Firefox 58.0.2 (-)